# Why are there no ellipsoidal drums?

Tags: waves, acoustics

It occurred to me today that all drums I could think of have circular heads. It then occurred to me that perhaps an elliptical drumhead would produce different overtones. Do the overtones produced by an elliptical drumhead not sound pleasant? And as a more general question, how does a general drumhead reverberate? What are the equations for a drumhead described by a certain polar curve's, its standing waves?

Comment: Related: http://www.math.ust.hk/~machas/drum/.    Also,I am pretty sure not all drum heads are circular.  Sounding pleasant is a cultural thing, I am sure you know of the different tonal scales found pleasant by different cultures.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathieu_function for elliptical drumheads

Comment: @Countto10 I couldn't think of any non-circular drum heads.

Comment: True, I could be wrong, and this is semantics as to definition of a drum, but the Wikipedia article says most are circular,. I looked through pictures on google. Maybe I am thinking of something like a hand played bongo that is  distorted in a picture through tilting it. Or I got confused by the body shape.  +1

Comment: @Countto10 Doing more research I stumbled onto this http://drummagazine.com/trixon-a-strange-tale-of-an-odd-drum-set/]which is a non-circular drum. So it looks like you were right.

Comment: When watching TV, you are listening to the sound, or looking at the drum and the hands of the drummer, especially bongos,  are moving so fast, you can't see the head clearly, only the often elliptical body . So it's a bit distracting.  I thought for a hard, rigid head, you could get away with producing a fairly basic beat. Bongos are not subtle.....

Comment: Well, some of you may not remember the 1980s music scene, but I do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simmons_(electronic_drum_company). Most notable performance: Alexei Sayle singing ["Doctor Martin's Boots" on "The Young Ones"](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&ved=0ahUKEwjy6cGErr_VAhWCn5QKHR41BpoQtwIIWDAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DDfMy1V7Ma8E&usg=AFQjCNFOT-c5fA2VqWwZppiyVLqe0WKxCw)

Comment: And, as another example, you can even buy an elliptical drum: http://www.boehmemusic.com/en/drums/sewat-lodge-drum.html

Comment: Two practical reasons are (1) to make fitting the head to the drum easier  (with an ellipse you can only use a head with the correct major and minor axis lengths, and you have to orientate it accurately) and (2) it is relatively easy to tension a circular head evenly "by ear" to get a clean-sounding tone, but an elliptical head would be much harder to do since there are two distinct tones in any case, as the mathematical answers demonstrate.

Comment: Perhaps not a perfectly elliptical form, but [steel drums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steelpan) come to mind as another counter-example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect the actual answer is something boring like ease of manufacture and tuning.

However, one can work out the solutions for the wave equation in elliptic coordinates, perform a separation of variables and end up with a system of differential equations admitting Mathieu functions as solutions. The boundary value problem can be solved relatively straightforwardly [1-4].

(Following [3]) In elliptic coordinates $\xi,\eta$, $x=f \cosh(\xi)\cos(\eta), y=f\sinh(\xi)\sin(\eta)$ where $f$ is the distance from the origin to the foci $(\pm f,0)$. $0\leq \xi < \infty$ is the "radial" coordinate constant on ellipses and $0\leq \eta < 2\pi$ is the "polar" coordinate constant on hyperbolas. The solutions of the wave equation $$\psi(\xi,\eta,t)=T(t)R(\xi)\Theta(\eta)$$ split into the time part $$T''(t)+k^2\nu^2T=0,$$ and the two spatial parts $$R''(\xi)-(\alpha-2q\cosh(2\xi))R(\xi)=0$$ (modified Mathieu equation) and $$\Theta''(\eta)+(\alpha-2q\cos(2\eta))\Theta(\eta)=0$$ (ordinary Mathieu equation) where $-k^2, \alpha$ are the constants of separation and $q=k^2f^2/4$.

One interesting difference from circular membranes is that for each mode there is an even and odd mode, and they oscillate with different frequencies [3]. So if you stimulate one of the modes it is likely to produce a mix of two frequencies that likely do not have a nice rational ratio, and hence does not sound very harmonious. By changing the eccentricity they can likely be made to fit [4], but I suspect this will not make the whole spectrum harmonious.

[1] E. Mathieu, M´e moire sur le mouvement vibratoire d’une membrane de forme elliptique, J. Math. Pures Appl., vol. 13, pp. 137-203, 1868. http://sites.mathdoc.fr/JMPA/PDF/JMPA_1868_2_13_A8_0.pdf

[2] http://booksite.elsevier.com/9780123846549/Chap_Mathieu.pdf

[3] http://optica.mty.itesm.mx/pmog/Papers/P001.pdf

[4] http://www.altenberg.com/peter/pdfs/mathJournalSamp.pdf

Comment: Another paper with the calculations: http://www.altenberg.com/peter/pdfs/mathJournalSamp.pdf

Comment: Notes at rational multiples sound harmonious *because* typical instruments (not drums) have their harmonics rationally spaced. So tuning a drum to have rationally spaced harmonics won't make it sound any better. Instead the trick would be to tune two drums so that they share a lot of harmonics (more precisely, so that they fail to have a lot of "near misses" between their harmonics). Then they would sound nice together.